# Grails - rendering div with a javascript call within a remoteSubmit

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a situation where I want to hit a button in the GSP (actionSubmit) and update a div when I finish the call (which includes a call to a javascript function). I want to ultimate end up in the controller rendering the searchResults parameter and the div with the results (which is currently working).

Problem is, I need to (presumably) wrap my actionSubmit in a remoteForm. But how do I:
1) Run the javascript method already existent in the onClick
2) Render the page in the controller.

If I try both wrapped in a controller, I finish the remoteForm action and the javascript action "hangs" and never finishes.

Any ideas?

List.gsp

```
   <g:actionSubmit type="button" value="Ping All" onclick="getIds('contactList');"/>

    function getIds(checkList)
        {
            var idList = new Array(); 
            jQuery("input[name=" + checkList + "]:checked").each 
            ( 
                function() { 
                    idList.push(jQuery(this).val()); 
                } 
            );

            $.ajax({ 
                url: "pingAll", 
                type:"GET", 
                data:{ids:JSON.stringify(idList)}
            });
        }
```

controller:

```
def pingAll() {

    String ids = params.ids
    if(ids == "[]") {
        render(template:'searchResults', model:[searchResults:""])
        return
    }

    def idArray = contactService.formatIDString(ids)

    idArray.each {
        def contactInstance = Contact.get(Integer.parseInt(it))
        emailPingService.ping(contactInstance)
    }

    /**
    * Added this on 3/13. Commented out line was initial code.
    */
    def searchResults = contactSearchService.refactorSearchResults(contactSearchService.searchResults)
    render(template:'searchResults', model:[searchResults:searchResults, total:searchResults.size()])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1) You can avoid using the Grails remote tags (formRemote, remoteField, etc.), and I really encourage you to explore and understand how they work. The Grails remote tags are generally not very flexible. The best way to learn how they work is to just write some sample tags using the examples from the Grails online docs and then look at the rendered page in a web browser. All the tags do generally speaking are output basic html with the attributes you define in your Grails tags. Open up your favorite HTML source view (i.e. Firebug) and see what Grails outputs for the rendered HTML.

The reason I say this is because, the code you've written so far somewhat accomplishes what I've stated above, without using any GSP tags.

g:actionSubmit *submits* the form you are working in using the controller action you define (which you haven't here, so it runs the action named in your value attribute). However, you also have an onClick on your actionSubmit that is running an AJAX call that also submits data to your pingAll action. Without seeing the rest of your code and what else is involved in your form, you are submitting your form twice!

You can simply just not write actionSubmit, and simply do an input of type button (not submit) with an onClick. Then in your javascript function that runs, define a jQuery success option for your AJAX call

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "pingAll", 
    type:"GET", 
    data:{ids:JSON.stringify(idList)},
    success:function(data) {
        $('#your-updatedDiv-id-here').html(data);
    }
});
```

2) If you want to use the GSP tags, I think you are using the wrong one. Without knowing the full extent of your usage and form data involved, it looks like g:formRemote, g:submitToRemote, and g:remoteFunction could serve your purposes. All have attributes you can define to call javascript before the remote call, as well as defining a div to update and various event handlers.

Comment: Bingo for the javascript entry. I was able to update my services variable during the pingAll call and handle the html refresh in Javascript. Thank YOU!